# Add then remove in dictionary

Tags: python

This is my code

```
def make_directory():
    return []


def get_number(directory, person):
    a = dict(directory)
    if person in a:
        return a[person]
    else:
        return 0


def add_number(directory, person, number):
    directory.append((person,number))
    return(str(person) + ' ' +'added!')    





def del_number(directory, person):
    a = dict(directory)
    if person in a:
        del a[person]
        return (str(person) + ' ' +'deleted!')
    else:
        return 'Not found!'



def print_list(directory):
    print(directory)
phonebook = make_directory()
add_number(phonebook, 'Police', 999)
add_number(phonebook, 'Lynna', 8444)
add_number(phonebook, 'Jack', 1123)
add_number(phonebook, 'Sister', 5720)
print(get_number(phonebook, 'Jack'))
print(add_number(phonebook, 'Alex', 6346))
print(del_number(phonebook, 'Alex'))
```

When I try to `print(print_list(phonebook))` I am getting `[('Police', 999), ('Lynna', 8444), ('Jack', 1123), ('Sister', 5720), ('Alex', 6346)]` instead of  `[('Jack', 1123), ('Lynna', 8444), ('Police', 999), ('Sister', 5720)]`.

Why did the `del_number()` function call not remove `'Alex'`?

Comment: could you please explain what you are trying to do ?

Comment: @sjcipher: build a phone directory, add names, and remove names. But the removing fails.

Comment: To the close voter: how is not understanding the relationship between a list and a dictionary created from that list a 'simple typographical error'? The problem in the posted code can *certainly* be reproduced, so the CV seems entirely misplaced.

Answer (score 2):

Your `del_number()` function turns the list into a dictionary, then only removes the person from that dictionary, the original `directory` list is unaffected:

```
def del_number(directory, person):
    a = dict(directory)
    if person in a:
        del a[person]
```

You'd need to alter `directory` instead; you could use `list.remove()` once you've found the number:

```
def del_number(directory, person):
    a = dict(directory)
    if person in a:
        directory.remove((person, a[person]))
        return (str(person) + ' ' +'deleted!')
    else:
        return 'Not found!'
```

It would be a lot easier to do if your `directory` was a dictionary to begin with:

```
def make_directory():
    return {}

def add_number(directory, person, number):
    directory[person] = number
    return(str(person) + ' ' +'added!')
```

and remove the `dict()` calls in your other functions:

```
def del_number(directory, person):
    if person in directory:
        del directory[person]
        return (str(person) + ' ' +'deleted!')
    else:
        return 'Not found!'
```

Using a dictionary then lets you do things like:

```
def get_number(directory, person):
    return directory.get(person, 0)
```

e.g. return a default if `person` is not found in the dictionary.